# Weird behavior when calculating a simple expected utility using Expectation

Tags: probability-or-statistics, warning-messages

On Mathematica 11.0.1 (Win 10 - 64) I am getting rather strange results when calculating a simple expected utility:

```
(* discrete random variable for market *)
market = With[
    { states = {0, 1, 2} }, (* bad, average, good *)
    EmpiricalDistribution[ {0.5, 0.3, 0.2} -> states ]
];

(* utility function depending upon market and action 'found company' *)
utility = Function[ { m, f },
    Plus[
        Boole[ f == 0] × 0,
        Boole[ f == 1 && m == 0] × (-7),
        Boole[ f == 1 && m == 1] × 5,
        Boole[ f == 1 && m == 2] × 20
    ]
];

(* expected utility function for a given action f *)
eu = Function[ f,
    Expectation[ m × utility[ m, f ], m \[Distributed] market ]
];
```

Now we should be able to calculate the expected utility of founding our startup:

```
eu[1]
```

> 9.5

This is obviously wrong because `{0.5, 0.3, 0.2}.{-7,5,20}` is `2`.

Evaluating `Trace[ eu[1] ]` gives a long, long output, that contains lots of strange things like `Statistics'ExpectationDump'...`.

**Can anybody confirm this? And does anybody know what is going on here? (Bug?)**

Comment: You computed the expectation of `m * utility`. So `{0.5, 0.3, 0.2}.({0, 1, 2}*{-7, 5, 20})` which is 9.5

Comment: @Simon That is a blunder, indeed. It happens when one is mentally thinking about a sum or integral of weighted expressions. ;-)

Comment: @Simon Though I still find the Trace output "humongous" for such a little problem...

Comment: there's a lot going on behind the scenes in `Expectation`. It takes a smart human to see that this problem is a little nut, the dumb machine always employs the full sledgehammer.